# Error when trying to Approve Master Pages

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, list, error

I am editing a SharePoint Enterprise 2010 site and every time I edit a masterpage on any of our site collections I get the error "That item is no longer available. It may have been deleted by another user. Click "OK" to refresh the page."

But when I click "OK" and the page refreshes, the page is still listed. This happens in all browsers.

At first it looked like some sort of JavaScript conflict but now I'm not so sure. Has anyone seen this error before on a master page library, or knows of a fix/cause?